# AudioSession Deprecated, how do I play my sounds without disrupting music on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
OSStatus e;
// initialize the audio session. don't know if you already do this.
e = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (e)
{
    NSLog(@"failed to start audiosession: %i", (int)e);

}
// ***********************************************************
// * THIS IS THE CODE THAT MAKES OTHER AUDIO BE ABLE TO PLAY *
// ***********************************************************
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category);
// ***********************************************************
// *                         HOORAY                          *
// ***********************************************************
// activate the audio session. don't know if you already do this.
e = AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
if (e)
{
    NSLog(@"failed to make audiosession active: %i", (int)e);
}
```

This is the code I use to play sounds in my games without disrupting music in the background. However, most of this is deprecated now. What do I replace it with in iOS 7?

Comment: You better read [reference guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240).

Comment: I did read the reference guide. I still do not know what code to replace this with.